# Why Docsy hides the title at the beginning of the page in marked down?

Tags: html, css, hugo, docsy

I wanted to add some information regarding the Privacy statement to the static website that I am developing using the `Hugo` with `Docsy` theme. I have added a folder `content\en\privacy\_index.md` and written the content something like this:

```
---
title: "Privacy"
linkTitle: "Privacy"
tags : [""]
weight: 30
menu:
  main:
    weight: 30
---

## Privacy Policy of Test Website

Updated on: 01 October 2022
```

But for some reason the title `##  Privacy Policy of Test Website` is hidden under the `navbar` label. I did not make any changes to styles or `_baseof.html` page still why this is happening? How to fix this? This is happening for all other pages as well when I add a new folder and add some contents to my `.md` files. I can add breakline to fix this but wanted to fix a single place where this issue is occurring rather than adding line breaks in all files.

[image]